# How to extract a list of languages from textfile?

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have a lot of text files which all containing a line like this :

```
Sprachen: Deutsch, Englisch

Spricht: Englisch; 
Italienisch

Sprachen: wenig Deutsch, Englisch

sprachen:\ndeutsch russisch

spricht: wenig Englisch Russisch\n

etc...
```

How would you extract the languages listed into an array of strings?

I constructed a regex :

```
(sprachen*|spricht)\:+\s*(\w+[\s,;]*\w*)
```

But it fails to match after the second word of a list. If a space is in between the second and the third word. So I can't get the full list of languages.

Comment: I think it would be difficult to work it correctly doing it your way. Doing it by hand or having a list with all languages would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: This is a little difficult. Because in the end i want to extract the full list of languages out of the text files. I don't know all languages in advance.
Edit: But it is worth thinking of ot. Maybe I find a general list of all languages of the world and than match the text against it.

Comment: I know but there is no other way to have a list. I think this would be a good starting point to create the list I sproke about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers

Comment: You definitely helped me getting a new idea. I will think about getting a global list of all languages and than matching the text against it.

Comment: an other starting point micht be the ISO codes for languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: This may be the solution. But I have to think about the source text. It has to be always the same languages so my strings will match correctly. But this is work for tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know *a priori* the list of all the possible languages, an alternative approach could be cleaning your string before processing: *e.g.* you could convert it to lowercase, replace all the occurrences of the extra words ('sprachen', 'spricht', 'etc...', 'wenig', *etc.*) and separators (colons, semicolons, *etc.*).
Then it is easy to find all the languages.

```js
let str = `Sprachen: Deutsch, Englisch

Spricht: Englisch; 
Italienisch

Sprachen: wenig Deutsch, Englisch

sprachen:\ndeutsch russisch

spricht: wenig Englisch Russisch\n

etc...`;
str = cleanStr(str);
let langs = [];
str.split('\n').forEach(row => {
  row = row.trim();
  if (row) {
    row.split(' ').forEach(lang => {
      lang = lang.trim();
      if (!langs.includes(lang)) {
        langs.push(lang);
      }
    });;
  }
});
console.log(langs);

function cleanStr(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.replace(/(sprachen|spricht):(\s)+/g, '');
  str = str.replace(/wenig /g, '');
  str = str.replace(/;/g, '');
  str = str.replace(/,/g, '');
  str = str.replace(/etc.../g, '');
  return str;
}
```